# Date Picker in javascript that will not accept past and current date

Tags: javascript

Here's my code:

```
<script type="text/javascript" src="calendar_date_picker.js"></script>
<script type="text/javascript">
  var cdp1 = new CalendarDatePicker();
  var props = {
    debug :         true,
    excludeDays :       [6,0,1],
    excludeDates :      ['20081225','20081226','20091225','20091226'],
    minimumFutureDate : 5,
    formatDate :        '%m-%d-%y'
  };
  var cdp2 = new CalendarDatePicker(props);
  props.formatDate = '%d-%m-%y';
  var cdp3 = new CalendarDatePicker(props);
  cdp3.endYear = cdp3.startYear + 1;
  var cdp4 = new CalendarDatePicker(props);
  cdp4.addDisabledDatas("new Date =< new Date");
</script>
```

Comment: I think you need to provide more details.  What's your question?  Have you tried using Jquery UI's datepicker?

Comment: Here is the calendar the OP is using http://devshed.excudo.net/scripts/javascript/source/calendar+date+picker

Answer (score 1):

Try:

```
 var props = {
    debug :         true,
    excludeDays :       [6,0,1],
    excludeDates :      ['20081225','20081226','20091225','20091226'],
    minimumFutureDate : [5, false],
    formatDate :        '%m-%d-%y'
    };
```

From the documentation:

minimumDate - dates before this date are not selectable. format: yyyymmdd
maximumDate - dates after this date are not selectable. format: yyyymmdd
minimumFutureDate - same as minimum date but defined as an offset on the current date. must be set as an array of which the second argument indicates whether excluded days should be considered as well

http://devshed.excudo.net/scripts/javascript/source/calendar+date+picker

Answer (score -1):

Also have a look at this page:
http://devshed.excudo.net/scripts/javascript/calendar_date_picker_help.php

It contains a list of all the properties you can modify. The startYear property might also be of interest to you